# Counting how many words are over a certain limit in a string Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Thank you all for help on previous part. I have now finished that.
However changing title slightly and rewording question I now say that this is my code.

```
s = raw_input("Enter your text: ")

longestWord = max(s.split(), key=len)

k = list(s)

count = len(k)

wordsOver = []

over = count - 140

def numLen(s, n):
    return sum(1 for x in s.split() if len(x) >= n)
    for x in s.split():
        if len(x) >= n:
            wordsOver.insert(0, x)

val = numLen(s, 7)

if count > 140:
    print ("Sorry, that is more than 140 characters.")
    print ("You had a total of " + str(count) + " characters.")
    print ("That's " + str(over) + " over the max allowed.")
    print ("You're longest word was, " + longestWord)
    print ("There are " + str(val) + " words over 7 characters.")
    print ("They were:")
    print (wordsOver)
    print ("You may want to consider changing them for shorter words.")
else:
    print ("That's short enough!")
```

So now what I'm looking for is why the displaying of the words that are over isn't working, why and how to fix it. BTW for a little help it's the wordsOver bit that's broken

Comment: Why not just use `len(string)` ?

Comment: `if string[i].isalpha()` is your problem.  `str.isalpha()` returns `True` if the string contains only letters and `False` otherwise.  `' '.isalpha()` is `False` and therefore not counted.

Comment: `for i in range(len(string))` is better written as `for c in string`.  There is no need to use a loop counter.

Comment: Thank you all. Just adding to the question now. I intend on searching through it, having it say 1 - what length it is and 2 - what words are over a certain length.

Comment: If you are trying to count letters and spaces without punctuation do `if c.isalpha() or c.isspace()`.  If you want numbers too do `if c.isalnum() or c.isspace()`.  Or if you want to count everything `len(mystring)` is the solution.

Comment: Perhaps I should give context as it appears I was too vague. I will be making a program for twitter where you type in your text, and it will tell you if it is too long and by how many characters. If it is too long it will suggest words that are over 7-8 characters to be replaced with other shorter words.
Perhaps this will help with the answers here. Also thanks for all the fast feedback, I though this would just be glanced over as a stupid noob question.

Comment: `split` the text and look for long words in the resulting list.

Comment: `k = list(string)`
`count = len(k)`

or a code snippet like:

`count = 0`
`for char in string:`
`count += 1`

Comment: You need to know the total char count (everything that a user has typed) first and then pick the longest words which you should know how to.

Comment: For future reference it's best not to edit your questions to make new questions because people have already helped and now their answers don't reflect the question. If someone finds this question in future it'll be more difficult for them to get to the fix. Don't worry, you'll have your rep points higher soon enough so can ask more frequently. I know it's frustrating at first, so many questions. Everyone will be keen to help you if you're keen to learn, just have patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

I think this is what you want to do. In your numLen function you need to use `append()` rather than `insert()` when adding to your list. This is because when using insert you're not incrementing the index so each time you insert at index 0 you overwrite any value that's already there. Append does the legwork of finding out where the end of your list is and puts what you pass to it onto the end.

```
s = raw_input("Enter your text: ")

longestWord = max(s.split(), key=len)

k = list(s)

count = len(k)

wordsOver = []

over = count - 140

def numLen(s, n):
    for x in s.split():
        if len(x) >= 7:
            wordsOver.append(x)
    return len(wordsOver)

val = numLen(s, 7)

if count > 140:
    print ("Sorry, that is more than 140 characters.")
    print ("You had a total of " + str(count) + " characters.")
    print ("That's " + str(over) + " over the max allowed.")
    print ("You're longest word was, \"" + longestWord + "\"")
    print ("There are " + str(val) + " words over 7 characters.")
    print ("They were:")
    print (wordsOver)
    print ("You may want to consider changing them for shorter words.")
else:
    print ("That's short enough!")
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I didn't know that the insert overrode the word there, I thought that it would just add in at the start.

Answer (score 0):

in the for loop you're looking at each character and checking if that character `i` is a character that is in an alphabet using `.isalpha()` which will return false when it encounters a space since it is not alphabetic.

See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha

Answer (score -1):

isalpha() doesn't return true for whitespace.

Additionally, there are a whole slew of better ways to do this.  You should look at the Counter class in collections.  It's a dictionary that will provide you with what you need.

Comment: The OP is looking for `len(string)`: `Counter` is unnecessary

Comment: @brianpck you appear to be correct, I thought he wanted the count of the individual letters.  My bad.